# Writing retreat to Ireland

Tags: ireland, recommendations

My girlfriend and I are planning a one-week writing retreat to Ireland, but we're finding it difficult to find a place that is:

- Relatively cheap (i.e., around 300 euros for 6 nights)
- "Traditionally Irish" (i.e., a small-ish town in the middle of nowhere ... with at least one pub!)
- Not impossible to get to from an Irish airport by a combination of train and bus
- Is available in the beginning of July

Do you have any recommendations for how to find such a place?

Comment: Have you tried AirBnB?

Comment: Good point! It's difficult to know where in Ireland to look for an AirBnB, though. It's either in a big city like Dublin (which is not what we're looking for), or somewhere that's impossible to get to by bus.

Comment: As soon as you get out of the larger towns, it’s going to be quite difficult to find places reachable by train and bus IMHO.

Comment: It should be pretty quick to find out though... There are only 78 places available on AirBnb once you pick July 1-7, private place, less than 50 euros a night. Once you have eliminated any that don’t suit you for other reasons, it’s just a matter of checking for directions on Google Maps.

Comment: Or a pub with B&B? http://www.ireland-guide.com/ten-of-the-best/pubs-with-bandb---ten-of-the-best.8764.html You might be able to negotiate a discount for a 6 night stay

Comment: Even if the place is unreachable by bus, the owner may agree to pick you up.

Comment: Let me know how my answer helps. When you say "writing retreat", do you literally want to lock yourselves up with two laptops for a week and have them push food under the door :) , or do you want to go hang out for inspiration, where (say) Yeats, Joyce, Heaney, Tóibín used to go, see some scenery and history, go for a swim, have a pint, hear live music, meet the locals...? Tell me more about the sort of thing you want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A traditional **B&B (Bed & Breakfast)** will be a better option for two people sharing than an AirBnb; also breakfast is included (a full Irish breakfast, not just cereal, toast and tea.)

- see [www.bandbireland.com](http://www.bandbireland.com) for listings. There are [many more B&Bs than Airbnbs in Ireland](https://www.irishtimes.com/life-and-style/travel/ireland/the-full-irish-how-b-bs-bounced-back-1.3423944). Somewhat ironically, some B&Bs also list on Airbnb (and Booking.com, et al).
- **Advantages:** B&Bs always serve you a proper breakfast. You may get more privacy. The hosts may be more friendly and not have to rush out to work (not stressed-out people trying to cover their mortgage by AirBnb'ing a spare bedroom) and can suggest you places to go and give advice; look for reviews of places popular with foreign visitors. Some B&Bs are over a pub.
- **Availability & Price:** for example, I found 45 options in County Galway under €300 alone for your spec (6 nights from 7/1/2019 for two people sharing).
- **Reachable from an airport by train+bus:** first figure out are you flying into Dublin, Cork, Shannon, Knock or Belfast (NI)? And look at the train and bus maps.
- Search listings on [www.bandbireland.com](http://www.bandbireland.com) and turn on Map view. Or read the official tourist site https://www.ireland.com for guides and inspiration.
- **"Traditional small-ish town in the middle of nowhere"** Do some reading of guides and reviews, but most of Ireland (RoI and NI) outside the major cities fits your description:
- east/southeast: County Kilkenny, Carlow, Wicklow, Kildare, Laois, Waterford, Wexford are all near Dublin. I imagine you'll probably fly into Dublin Airport as it has the most flights, also the train+bus network.
- south and southwest (Cork, Kerry, Tipperary, Clare, Limerick). Fly into Cork Airport if possible.
- Galway (in the west) is a very literary place, great scenery, history and affordable; direct train from Dublin. Galway City is nice, as is County Galway; the further west you go, the harder to get to and sparsely populated, but also very scenic (bring your raincoat). If I remember, Galway City has the most bookshops-per-capita of any Irish city. You might fall in love with Galway.
- the northwest: Mayo, Sligo, Donegal are all nice but a bit harder to get to (>4 hours from Dublin)
- the midlands: sometimes said to be boring but has some gems and you might find something you like (Birr, Co. Offaly for example). Here are [some tips](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g186591-i88-k4164956-The_Midlands_What_to_see_there-Ireland.html). There are some small towns on the Shannon, where you get the river cruiser tourists passing through.
- border/northwest:

  - [Patrick Kavanagh country](https://patrickkavanaghcentre.com/) is in Co. Monaghan.
  - Yeats Country (WB Yeats) is Co Sligo
- Northern Ireland is also very nice too. Land of such literary giants as Séamas Heaney, CS Lewis, the Brontes and others.
  The [Séamas Heaney Homeplace](https://seamusheaneyhome.com) is said to be a mind-blowingly great museum and arts events centre, in Bellaghy, Co. Derry. 2hrs by train/bus from Belfast. And of course you must see the local sights like the Giants Causeway, Rope Bridge of Carrick-a-Rede, Dark Trees, Enniskillen, etc.
- You can search for literary holidays, summer schools, festivals, etc. The universities have some summer activities too.
- one random guide I found: ["Ireland literary itinerary - Ireland: by the Book"](https://www.ireland.com/en-us/itineraries/ireland-by-the-book/)
- a 10-day itinerary for a tour you can't afford, but the itinerary is a useful read: [Destinations Ireland & Beyond: Grand Literary Tour of Ireland](http://www.destinations-ireland.com/travel-interests/group-travel/literary-tour-of-ireland/)

Hope this gives you a couple of ideas :) Happy writing. Remember a proper raincoat.